# Copy files while preserving original file information (creation time etc.)

Tags: r, windows-7, file-management, file-copying

In order to ease the manual copying of large file amounts, I often use [FreeFileSync](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/). I noticed that it preserves the original file information such as when a file was created, last modified etc.

Now I need to regularly copy tons of files in batch mode and I'd like to do it in R. So I wondered if R is capable of preserving that information as well. AFAIU, `file.rename()` and `file.copy()` alter the file information, e.g. the times are set to the time the files were actually copied.

Is there any way I can restore the original file information after the files have been copied?

Comment: What's your operating system?

Comment: On Unix-like operating systems, you can use `rsync -a`, `cp -a`, or even `tar` (there are `tar` and `untar` commands in R, so it may work on Windows as well).

Comment: @MatthewPlourde: sorry, forgot. It's Windows 7 (64bit)

Comment: @VincentZoonekynd: thanks, I will have a look at them

Comment: Good question. `rsync` on Windows (which comes with Rtools, for instance) doesn't seem to support the "extended attributes" `-X` option which preserves file creation times on other OS's. The closest thing I see is to use `zip()` and then `unzip(..., setTimes=TRUE)`. It's not a perfect substitute though. It seems to change some times by 1 second for some reason, and requires more attention to the current working directory, destination directory, etc.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien: thanks for the info, especially for the pointer to `rsync` on Windows!

Comment: `file.rename()` does preserve date modified and date created (at least for me on Win7 64 bit).  I use `file.rename()` instead of `file.copy()` for that reason.  But obviously you can't use it copy just rename or move.

Comment: @ChrisHolbrook: right, I forgot to explicitly state that I'm after *copying* files from one drive to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robocopy via `system2()` can keep the timestamps.

```
> cmdArgs<- paste( normalizePath( file.path(getwd()), winslash="/"),
 normalizePath( file.path(getwd(), "bkup"), winslash="/" ),
  "*.txt",
 "/copy:DAT /V" )
> system2( "robocopy.exe", args=cmdArgs )
```

Robocopy has a slew of switches for all different types of use cases and can accept a 'job' file for the params and file names.  The ability of R to call out using system could also be used to execute an elevated session (perhaps the easiest would be by using a powershell script to call Robocopy) so that all of the auditing info (permissions and such) could be retained as well.